# How to use GPU in Blender Render?

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine, gpu

I currently am unable to find the options to use the GPUs I have to render some footage in blender. Im using the Blender Rendering engine, but I dont have an option to use the GPUs, even though I enabled CUDA rendering in the preferences. Thanks for any help or insight.

My GPUs are GTX 980s, and I have the most recent driver installed.

Comment: Please state your operating system. Windows, Linux, Mac, Joes.

Comment: I'm affraid Blender Internal is using CPU only.

Comment: My operating system is Windows 8.1. Rendering an animation in 720p still takes a horribly long time with a 6-core processor :/